# Can you redirect "My Sites" page to another page?

Tags: my-site

Can the "My Sites" page be made to redirect users to another SharePoint page?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to achieve, but the answer is yes. Open your mysites in SharePoint Designer and put this in mysite15.master or (maybe) default.aspx

window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

Comment: Thanks, the code worked on mysite15.master on my personal site. But I'm looking to redirect the My Sites page for all users to a particular page, and that tactic does not appear to be working :/

Comment: I assume that's because everyone has a different site collection and hence .master. Try putting it in default.aspx which loads for everybody when they initially hit their mysite.

Comment: Added it to that page and now the Newsfeed link redirects where I want My Sites to redirect to -_-